# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method. 'ZXing ScannerView'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, zxing

I understand why I'm receiving this error but I need help fixing it.

This is the error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.adampatel.application/com.example.adampatel.application.Barcode}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.stopCamera()' on a null object reference
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
...

    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.stopCamera()' on a null object reference
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
...
```

So the concept behind this is an application that allows a user to scan a barcode and thereafter stores the value of that barcode within an `EditText` field.
However, the activity has other features available to the user which means they won't always use the scanner to scan a barcode resulting in the `EditText` remaining empty.

This is when the error occurs. When the `EditText` is left empty, no barcode has been scanned and the user wants to go back to the previous activity.

Is there any way I can continue to allow the user to navigate to the previous activity, regardless of there being no values entered in the `EditText` view?

Comment: Either catch the exception or create an empty object to return where ever the null object is causing an issue or put an if statement around the method call to check if the object is null before attempting to run the method that is causing the exception.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Apparently you are calling `stopCamera()` on a null `ZXingScannerView` Maybe you're creating `ZXingScannerView` only when the user scans something. You could do something like `if (mZXingScannerView != null) m ZXingScannerView.stopCamera()`

Answer (score 0):

The object you are using to call **stopCamera()** is null